# jQuery fadeIn after grouped toggle

Tags: jquery

I have the following but `$("span#slogan").fadeIn("slow");` does not run after the if statement has finished looping through the hidden elements.

How can I make it so that fadeIn is the last thing to run?

```
<style type="text/css">
#hidden span{
    display:none;
    float:left;
    font-size:20px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    function showDiv() {

        if($('#hidden span:not(#slogan)').is(':hidden')) {

            $('#hidden span:not(#slogan):hidden:first').show("bounce", { times:3 }, 500);  
            setTimeout(showDiv, 500);
        }

        $("span#slogan").fadeIn("slow");
    }

    $("button").click(function() {
        showDiv();
    });
});
</script>

<button>Click</button>

<div id="hidden">
    <span>T</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>x</span>
    <span>t</span>
    <span id="slogan">Slogan</span>
</div>
```

​
**Callback**

I can't use the callback on the `.show` because the `.show` runs four times because of the if loop, if I use the callback to fadeIn then I would have the same fadeIn four times.

Comment: I dont understand, you say that the fadeIn is the last thing that is running (after the If), and your question is how it will be the last thing that is runned?

Comment: At the moment the fadeIn runs before the loop in the if has finished, I'm trying to get the fadeIn only to run after the loop in the if has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created this JSFiddle for you, importent to notice is that I removed the bounce effect couse I was not able to include in the jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/3fEeb/

The key is to inside the callback check if all the spans are visible, if thats the case, fade In the slogan..

```
function showDiv() {
    if($('#hidden span:not(#slogan)').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#hidden span:not(#slogan):hidden:first').show("bounce", { times:3 },function() {        
            if($('#hidden span:not(#slogan):hidden:first').length==0){
                $("span#slogan").fadeIn("slow");
            }
        });  
        setTimeout(showDiv, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: but because it's looping it runs the 'callback' 4 times after each seperate `.show`

Comment: Where is the loop do you mean? The bounce 3 times?

Comment: All of the `span` are `display:none` so it applies the bounce affect on each `span`

Answer (score 1):

Just a way to do it without the setTimeout:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ujetes/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
function showDiv() {
  $('#hidden span:not(#slogan)').each(function(i,e){
    $(this).delay(i*300).show("bounce", { times:3 }, 500, function(){
      $('#slogan').fadeIn('slow');
    });  
  });     
}
```

---

**EDIT:** (To avoid `#slogan` fadeIn run 4/more times. See comments)

```
function showDiv() {
  var c = 0;
  $('#hidden span:not(#slogan)').each(function(i,e){
    c++;
    $(this).delay(i*300).show("bounce", { times:3 }, 500);
  });
  $('#slogan').delay(c*300).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ujetes/2/edit)*

---

using .length: **[demo3](http://jsbin.com/ujetes/3/edit)**

```
function showDiv() {
  $('#hidden span:not(#slogan)').each(function(i,e){
    $(this).delay(i*300).show("bounce", { times:3 }, 500);
  });
  $('#slogan').delay( $('#hidden span').length * 300 ).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Comment: Only problem is this runs the fadeIn four times, it needs to combine the selected answer to work properly.

Comment: @Silver89 Reedited. Added a counter into the each function. It counts all the elements and it passes that var to the #slogan delay too :) .

Answer (score 0):

```
function showDiv() {
    if($('#hidden span:not(#slogan)').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#hidden span:not(#slogan):hidden:first').show("bounce", { times:3 }, 500, function(){
            $("span#slogan").fadeIn("slow");
        });  
    }
}
```

That might do it for you.

Comment: Wouldn't the :first in the selector mean that there is only one thing using the bounce effect?

Comment: It's not even working for me, included jquery and jquery-ui scripts, click the button and nothing, no console error just nothing, also have set the #hidden { display:none; }, ok ive got it working I was being tardy, I see what you mean now.

Comment: Might need to use `$(document).ready(function(){` I'll update the code

Comment: OK I think the issue is that as soon as the first one is finished bouncing it fires the function again finding the next matched hidden span, need some way to count all the hidden spans and fire it at the end, or approach it slightly differently.